# Why can't I detect keypress while player is on top of chest

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write code where a player reacts to an OnTriggerEvent2D on a chest, and then opens the chest inventory. I have it so that the chests are randomly generated on the map, and the inventory is located on the scene.

I have tried moving the chest inventory to both the scene and the chest prefab.
I have added the interactable code to the chest prefab, and put the chest inventory as the gameObject when I had the chest inventory in the chest prefab. I am unable to do this when the inventory UI is located in the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ChestInteractable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] KeyCode interactableKey = KeyCode.E; //allow player to choose key

    public GameObject chestInventoryUI;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) //if player collides with chest (I am unsure if OnCollisionEnter2D is better, I am only a beginner)
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(interactableKey)) {
            chestInventoryUI.SetActive(true); //open up chest inventory
            Time.timeScale = 0f; //time is stopped
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(interactableKey))
        {
            chestInventoryUI.SetActive(false); //closes chest inventory
            Time.timeScale = 1f; //time resumes
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the chest inventory UI to be visible, and the game to be stopped, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try using `void OnTriggerStay2D (Collider2D collision)` because you want it to be called every frame there's an overlap.  Otherwise, the player would have to press the key down on the exact frame the overlap begins, which is not what you mean to do :)  Also I think using `private` on it might mess it up so just have it as `void ...` with no access modifier

Comment: Also be aware that a keydown and a keyup can happen during a *single* frame, especially with latency, so the `if(input.GetKeyDown(...))` and `if(Input.GetKeyUp(...))` blocks can both end up being executed as they both return true if the key event happened during the current frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [OnTriggerStay2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html)

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(interactableKey))
    {
        chestInventoryUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(interactableKey))
    {
        chestInventoryUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
    }
}
```